# Rashi on the Rif?

Tags: talmud-gemara, rashi, talmud-bavli, rif-rabbi-isaac-alfasi

Is Rashi on the Rif the same as the one in the Gemara?

If it is, why is it put there?

If its not, then why did Rashi write a different pirush on the Rif, and does it have a different Derech then Rashi on the Gemara?

Comment: +1 though I don't really follow your second question. It would have been put there to help in understanding the words of the Rif. That's why Rashi is printed anywhere. In any event, welcome to Mi Yodeya!

Comment: I don't know if this has historical backing, but someone told me that Rif was more popular than the Gemara in Rashi's time, and Rashi therefore wrote a pirush on Rif first, but I don't know how accurate this is.

Comment: @Efraim See [the introduction](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32867&st=&pgnum=2) to the Chafetz Chaim's *Likutei Halachos*. He mentions that, until the time of R' Yosef Karo, people studied the Rif primarily with Rashi's commentary. He advises people to take this approach in order to become familiar with the halachos in the Talmud, especially if they are not one of the few people who are able to directly assimilate and understand the entire Talmud.

Comment: Thanks for the Makor! I have seen that Inyan many times, especially among early Acharonim, that Pasken that one should learn Rif with Rashi if one doesn't have time to learn Gemara. Still though, question unanswered.

Comment: A [couple](http://www.myjewishlearning.com/texts/Rabbinics/Talmud/Gemara/Commentaries.shtml) of [links](http://books.google.com/books?id=_LKr2hmXMa8C&pg=PA232#v=onepage&q&f=false) of interest.

Comment: @Fred according to your links, the Rashi on Rif is just another manuscript, but has anyone done a study on this to prove it?

Comment: http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/1191-alfasi-isaac-ben-jacob  mentions Rashi on Rif, still no proof to the articles claim, and no answer to who put it there and why was it put there.

Comment: @Efraim I don't know, and I disclaim responsibility for any claims in the above links - I just posted them because I thought they were relevant. And the remark in your JE link in interesting, as well: "The so-called commentary of Rashi, found in some editions, consists merely of extracts from Rashi's general commentary on the Talmud."

Comment: http://rifyomi.blogspot.com/

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Thank you, I thought I had deleted that.

Answer (score 3):

The Rif has written his Halochos from Yerushalmi as well as Bavli and there is a Rashi commentary on that (in the Rif) e.g. see Berachos 8b (Rif pages) on the last of the narrow lines where he quotes the Yerushalmi and Rashi has a commentary on it - so for sure it's not exactly copied-and-pasted from the Gemara, in fact there are times that the Poskim quote the Rashi on the Rif because it's not in the Gemara.

As far as style it is the same.

Comment: ever any stiras?

Comment: Do you know it's actually rashi?

Comment: מרכבת המשנה ספר קנין הלכות שלוחין ושותפין פרק ח הלכה ד
מקום שנהגו להעלות שכר כתף וכו'. עיין השגות, והנה גירסת רש"י מקום שנהגו להעלות שכר כתף למעות לבהמה וחדא נקיט שמעלין שכר כיתוף של בהמה ליתן מעות למתעסק ובשם עגלים וסייחין. ואולם בפי' רש"י על הרי"ף גריס מקום שנהגו להעלות שכר כתף למעות מעלין לבהמה מעלין

Comment: I dont remember where I saw it, but modern day consensus is that it was authored by a 14th century German.  (I think he quotes laaz in German asopposed to French).

Answer (score 1):

http://web.nli.org.il/sites/NLI/English/collections/treasures/shapell_manuscripts/talmudic/rif/Pages/default.aspx

Last paragraph. Also look up Wikipedia רי״ף in Hebrew.

Comment: This is a link only answer. You should summarize what the link says about the matter and explain it in English.